# Android SearchView shows different layouts

Tags: android

I am defining a search action in my action bar. The search works perfectly. However, when touching the search icon a white background layout occurs (containing the app icon) and when touching the back arrow a blue layout occur (without the app icon).

My problem is that I only want to show the blue layout (appearing after touching the back arrow on the white layout).

Here are code relative to the search action bar implementation.

AndroidManifest:

```
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".RecipeListActivity" />


        </activity>

<activity
            android:name=".RecipeListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_recipe_list"
            android:parentActivityName=".RecipeFolderActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.cookbook.android.mycookbook.RecipeFolderActivity" />

           <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

This is the definition of the menu in xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.cookbook.android.mycookbook.MainFolderActivity" >

    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_loupe"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/add_main_folder"
        android:title="@string/add_main_folder"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

Here is the java code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_folder, menu);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id==R.id.search){
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"In onOptionItemSelected, for search");
            onSearchRequested();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. :-)

Comment: Screenshots of actual vs expected behavior would be super helpful here. :)

Comment: I wish! But the website does not let me. I need 10 reputations to do so... :(

Comment: You can upload to imgur, then post the URL within your question.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/gvEDn

The first photo correspond to the search layout I first have. Then clicking on the back arrow brings the layout of the following photo. I would like to obtain the second one directly.

Here you go! Thank you for your help